# repeat vectors vertically in an Array / Matrix, n times cat

Tags: arrays, matrix, julia, cat, ternary

I have

```
x = collect(1:9)
y = repeat([1],9)
```

producing

```
9-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9

9-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
```

And want to glue the two vectors together vertically, whereas some of the matrix columns are `x`, others `y`. I found that I can do that equivalently by running either one of those commands:

```
c0 = [x y x x x]
c1 = cat(x,y,x,x,x,dims=2)
```

producing

```
9×5 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  1  1  1  1
 2  1  2  2  2
 3  1  3  3  3
 4  1  4  4  4
 5  1  5  5  5
 6  1  6  6  6
 7  1  7  7  7
 8  1  8  8  8
 9  1  9  9  9
```

Now, I would like to dynamically put together a matrix with `x` and `y` columns based on a control vector, `V`, that can differ in length. I tried to do it in the following way, however, I will get a different data structure:

```
V = [false true false false false]
[v ? x : y for v in V]
```

producing:

```
1×5 Matrix{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

How can I solve this? I strictly need this structure, and I have a strong interest/preference in using the beautiful Julia fast vector/array code style, avoiding any multi-line for loops.

Comment: `y .* .!V + x .* V` is pretty terse

Comment: What is your expected output exactly? Please provide a minimal example.

Comment: You should absolutely more thoroughly consider using loops. Doing this in a contrived vectorized style will be highly inefficient (much slower and more memory intensive than loops), and also un-idiomatic, and probably much harder to read. If you have to create vectors to do vectorized style, then you are on the wrong path.

Comment: Thanks @DNF for noting. As a previous R user I believe I'm used to vectorized operations and have a preference for it as coding style, so I would probably ignore minor (even major) efficiency considerations in usual day-to-day implemenation. However, I'd love to know more about it and learn about which paradigms are state-of-the-art in Julia. Is there a resource you can share where I can read about it?

Comment: @DNF, would your concerns also apply to @ DonaldSeinen' solution?

Comment: @joffdd There's not necessarily anything wrong with the solutions themselves. But I am doubting that this matrix should be created and used in the first place. It is very low on information, repeated columns and repeated values. You can represent it as `1:9` and `1`, plus a control vector. You should probably loop over `V` and select `1:9` or `1` (or perhaps `1:1`) for each iteration. But I don't really know what you want this for. I suspect this is an 'XY-problem'.

Comment: @DNF I see. In my use case, I get vectors of data from a data source that make up most columns (here:`x`), whereas some columns are just filled with `1` as a way of imputation (here: `y`). So `x` is made up here, `y` shall do imputation, `V` is hardcoded to decide for each column whether to use the data vectors or force imputation. Actually `V` was intended to be a vector, not a one row matrix, as noted below in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
V = [true, false, true, true, true]
reduce(hcat, [v ? x : y for v in V])
```

This will first create the vector as you show and then stack the vector together horizontally.

An alternative is first create a matrix of the right size using for example

`M = zeros(Int64, length(x), length(V))`

and then fill it with the vectors you need

```
for (idx, i) in enumerate(V)
    M[:, idx] = i ? x : v
end
```

EDIT:

Adding this terse version proposed by @DonaldSeinen

`y .* .!V + x .* V`

Comment: Thanks @Giovanni! That's what I was looking for indeed. As I find @DonaldSeinen's solution clever too, would you mind including it here in the accepted answer for other people to find it?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that works and I feel may be helpful in given contexts:

Contrarily to the above (as I actually wanted to do), `V` is defined as a `5-element Vector{Bool}`, not `1×5 Matrix{Bool}`.

```
V = [false,true,false,false,false]
```

Then I can run the following:

```
using DataFrames
DataFrames.stack([v ? x : y for v in V])
```

Note that this is not going to create a DataFrame, it just uses the `stack` function and results in the `9×5 Matrix{Int64}` as required.

*Note:* I feel that there will probably be other, smarter ways to do exactly that without requiring a package, similar to the other answers above, but given that V shall be a vector. Happy to read suggestions in the comments and I will add them here.